# Correct re.compile to eliminate periods but add space for comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, text-processing

I have a few lines of python code that go through a list and removes punctuation from each row. Here the code runs

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = [['M.B.B.S'], ['M.B.B.S,B.S'],['ACN-P, D.N.P'],['ACNP-BC, DNP']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID']) 
p = re.compile(r'[^\w\s\d]+')
df['ID'] = [p.sub('',x) for x in df['ID'].tolist()]
df
```

The problem I am facing is that I need the periods, and dashes (".", "-") to be substituted for no space as they do above, yet the commas (",") to be substituted for spaces. I can't get the correct expression syntax.
For example line 2 gives the result "MBBSBS" when I need it to read "MBBS BS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the alternate replacement before the regex:

```
df['ID'] = [p.sub('',x.replace(',',' ')) for x in df['ID'].tolist()]
```

Or, just use the Python string method [.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and skip the regex entirely:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

repl={ord(k):'' for k in string.punctuation}
repl[ord(',')]=' '
data = [['M.B.B.S'], ['M.B.B.S,B.S'],['ACN-P, D.N.P'],['ACNP-BC, DNP']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID']) 

df['ID'] = [x.translate(repl) for x in df['ID'].tolist()]

>>> df
            ID
0         MBBS
1      MBBS BS
2    ACNP  DNP
3  ACNPBC  DNP
```

And if you don't want `', '` becoming two spaces, just replace those prior to other replacements:

```
df['ID'] = [x.replace(', ',' ').translate(repl) for x in df['ID'].tolist()]
```

You get the idea...

Comment: I appreciate this method as Ive never used .translate, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df['ID'] = df.ID.str.replace('[.-]|(,\\s*)',lambda x: ' ' if x.group(1) else '')
df
             ID
0          MBBS
1       MBBS BS
2      ACNP DNP
3    ACNPBC DNP
```

if that is complicated, do:

```
 df['ID'] = df.ID.str.replace('[.-]','').str.replace(',\\s*',' ')
 df
                 ID
    0          MBBS
    1       MBBS BS
    2      ACNP DNP
    3    ACNPBC DNP
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, although the other commenter provided a more useful solution. I like your method as well. Thanks!